# Using Teradata in Spring Batch - missing method isWrapperFor

Tags: java, spring-batch, teradata

I am trying to use Teradata in Spring Batch reader. Driver and connection to database seems fine. But i have a problem with DataSource Spring Batch bean - when i'm starting the app, it fails with the following message:

`Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.ncr.teradata.TeraDataSource does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean isWrapperFor(java.lang.Class)' of interface java.sql.Wrapper`

What i've tried:

1. making Spring believe that it is not Teradata bean, but Postgres (as i read that Spring Batch does not support Teradata directly) by changing driver and url names;
2. extending Teradata bean with custom implementation with isWrapper method provided (and using it in Spring Batch);
3. changing Teradata bean type from com.ncr.teradata.TeraDataSource to com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDataSource;
4. changing input parameter type in Spring reader to com.ncr.teradata.TeraDataSource.

Still no luck. Below is the code for my Spring batch reader and `DataSource` bean (they are actually in different classes):

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcCursorItemReader<CustomObject> reader(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<CustomObject> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    reader.setName("teradataJdbcReader");
    reader.setSql(TERADATA_SELECT_QUERY);
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setRowMapper(new CustomObjectRowMapper<>());
    return reader;
}

@Bean
public DataSource teraDataSource() {
    TeraDataSource teraDataSource = new TeradataDataSource();
    teraDataSource.setUser(username);
    teraDataSource.setPassword(pass);
    return teraDataSource;
}
```

UPD I have a second `DataSource` bean which i was using for H2. I tried to use that `DataSource` bean for Teradata, but the same error occures. Below is the code for that bean.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(pass);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is not a Spring Batch issue. You need to make sure you can correctly create a `DataSource` bean before using it in a Spring Batch job.

Comment: I created a second bean without using of TeraDataSource. It produces no error, correctly initializes and works ok with H2. So i guess it's working correctly, but not with Teradata. Added code to the question.

Comment: I managed to extend TeraDataSource and implement isWrapperFor method, and I could use it in jdbc connections to database. As for Spring Batch, I assumed that is does not support Teradata at all.

Comment: same issue i am facing any suggestions?